# I have an issue in Python Lists,how to solve it?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want a code in Python lists,to get all the possibility in a given list without using any built in functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
example = [1,2,3]
def expandList(ex):
    rslt = []
    for i in range(len(ex)):
        for j in range(len(ex)):
            rslt.append((ex[i], ex[j]))
    return rslt
expandList(example)
```

Yields:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Comment: Thank you guys,this was a big help

Answer (score 0):

If you are going for each permutation, you would use nested for loops. Example:

```
permutations = list()
for item in myList:
    for item2 in myList:
        permutations.append((item, item2))
```

This code will create a list of permutations.

Comment: For example: list = [1,2,3] , (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (3,1) (3,2) (3,3)

Comment: @Sayuki The new answer should fit your bill. You can use nested for loops to generate pairs.